# Caching Issues (Seeing entirely different versions of the website)

Tags: php, apache, caching

If a page or even just a word on a page gets updated I won't see the changes until physically pressing the refresh button on the browser. Sometimes I'll even see versions that haven't existed for days. Note this isn't a SHIFT-F5 or a cache reset, it's literally just pressing the refresh button, f5 or on mobile swiping down to refresh the page.

I redirect all traffic to a routing index.php for basic mvc layout.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

There is no PHP Opcache, there is nothing.

I have put this into .htaccess to make sure there is no caching.

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Going to a different computer in the house, the site will again, show the old version until you press refresh on the browser. It's driving me crazy and I have no idea whats going on.

Note: This is a shared hostgator server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cache problem with php file,you can use below code. It will remove your file from cache.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

If you are facing problem with any single css/js files, you can append the current date at end of url. So every time it loads from server not from cache

```
Example:
https://somewebiste.com/css/abcd.css?date=<?=date('ymdhis');?>
https://somewebiste.com/css/abcd.js?date=<?=date('ymdhis');?>
```